# How does Alt+F2 run a command directly as a child process of the init process?

Tags: systemd, process, lxde

On Lubuntu 18.04, if I click the desktop menu, and lxterminal in it, and run the the following in the terminal emulator window, I will get

```
$ pstree -a -p   -s $$
systemd,1 --system --deserialize 19
  └─lightdm,661
      └─lightdm,862 --session-child 12 19
          └─lxsession,944 -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
              └─lxpanel,1087 --profile Lubuntu
                  └─lxterminal,23017
                      └─bash,23020
                          └─pstree,26853 -a -p -s 23020
```

If I hit alt+F2, and run lxterminal and run the following in the terminal emulator window, I will get

```
$ pstree -a -p   -s $$
systemd,1 --system --deserialize 19
  └─lxterminal,1480
      └─bash,27000
          └─pstree,27013 -a -p -s 27000
```

How does the second make `lxterminal` run directly as a child of `systemd`? Is it done by orphaning the lxterminal process and reparenting it to `systemd`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man nohup`, which explains how to detach a process from the parent. Process 1 is made the parent. One of `init`'s tasks is to harvest (and ignore) the process's `exit` status, and prevent "zombie" processes.

Comment: Can you explain the relation betw nohup and alt+F2?

Comment: Not in a comment. Read `man -k process`, `man execve`, `man -a fork`

Comment: you missed the question in my post. sorry to point that out.

Comment: Alt-F2 starts `lxterminal` with the `fork` and `exec` calls. Learning about them, and the other `man` pages will show you that I did explain how. Read the manuals, Luke!

Comment: Who is "Luke"? Do I remind you of someone you knew? I know what fork and exec do. I was asking about how alt+F2 runs a command as a child of the init process. The references you gave are about fork and exec and process. They and your reply don't address my question.

Comment: It's a SMOP between what you type to Alt-F2 and `fork/exec`. Processes must have parents, but with `fork/exec` one can say "I'm not the parent!". `init` (PID 1) is the default parent, see above. Or are you asking "what program handles Alt-F2"?